# How do I change an image on three fragments

Tags: android, static, fragment

I have a three fragment project. I want to change an image on each fragment from a play image to a pause image. I have a public class called Global. From FragmentA I would like to call the  Global.setCntrlImage() routine. This routine will change the three images on the three fragments.

Here if the FragmentA call to Global class.

```
                if (Global.player.isPlaying()) {    
                  Global.stopPlay();
                  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                  Global.setCntrlImage("play");
                  Global.playing = false;
                     }
```

Here is my Global class.

```
public class Global  {

public static boolean playing = false;
public static MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

public static void stopPlay() {
    //Log.d(APP_TAG, "stopping playback..");
    //printResult("stop playing..");
    player.pause();
    player.reset();
    playing = false;
}

public static void startPlay(Context context, String fn) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Log.d(APP_TAG, "starting playback..");
        final String APP_TAG = "com.hascode.android.soundrecorder";

        if (player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.seekTo(0);
        }

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getResources().getAssets().openFd(fn);
            player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
            playing = true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.w(APP_TAG, "illegal state .. player should be reset");
        } catch (IOException e) {
             //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.w(APP_TAG, "Could not write to sd card");
        }
        //System.out.println("playing = " + playing);
        //System.out.println("Song duration is " + player.getDuration());       
}


public static void setCntrlImage(String cntrl){
    //get image object from fragmentB, How?
    ImageView image = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    if (cntrl == "play"){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    }       
}
```

The method getView() is undefined for type Global. How can I change the images on the three fragments, A, B, and C.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not handle this through your activity?

Comment: then you can just create an iterface in the Global class and implement that interface in you fragments. where you can get instant callback as soon as you hit that pause button. and in that callback method change imagaview of your fragment.

Comment: or you can write a singelton Iamgeview class which you can put in those three fragments and from Global class you can set image to all of them by just calling a single method.

Comment: See link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try to handle through my activity.